# Matrix Structure for screen rotation

Tags: x11, monitors, xrandr

I can set my screen rotation to inverted with:

```
xrandr -o inverted
xinput set-prop 'ELAN Touchscreen' 'Coordinate Transformation Matrix' -1 0 1 0 -1 1 0 0 1
```

and back to normal with:

```
xrandr -o normal
xinput set-prop 'ELAN Touchscreen' 'Coordinate Transformation Matrix' 1 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 1
```

I found a HowTo here: https://wiki.ubuntu.com/X/InputCoordinateTransformation
So I guess for (90° to the right) it will be:

```
# ⎡ 0 -1 1 ⎤
# ⎜ 1  0 0 ⎥
# ⎣ 0  0 1 ⎦
right='0 -1 1 1 0 0 0 0 1'
```

But What is the right 'Coordinate Transformation Matrix' to the left?

Comment: Wouldn't it be [[0 1 0] [-1 0 1] [0 0 1]]. I.e. `x` and `y` are still swapped but it changes which of them that is inverted. The inverted coordinate has -1 in the upper-left 2x2 and 1 to the right, while the non-inverted coordinate have 1 in the upper-left 2x2 and 0 to the right.

Comment: Note: by now the wiki page also includes the answer to the left matrix

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Judging from the question it is a standard coordinate transform matrix.

So:

```
⎡x_out⎤   ⎡ a b c ⎤   ⎡ x_in ⎤
⎜y_out⎥ = ⎜ d e f ⎥ * ⎜ y_in ⎥
⎣z_out⎦   ⎣ 0 0 1 ⎦   ⎣ z_in ⎦
```

with `z_out` = `z_in` = 1.

I.e.

```
x_out = a * x_in + b * y_in + c
y_out = d * x_in + e * y_in + f
```

The example matrix you gave for right rotation

```
⎡ 0 -1 1 ⎤
⎜ 1  0 0 ⎥
⎣ 0  0 1 ⎦
```

thus means

```
x_out = 1 - y_in
y_out = x_in
```

for rotating left it would be the other way around i.e.:

```
x_out = y_in
y_out = 1 - x_in
```

giving the matrix

```
⎡  0 1 0 ⎤
⎜ -1 0 1 ⎥
⎣  0 0 1 ⎦
```

Answer (score 0):

The last missing Matrix will be

```
left='0 1 0 -1 0 1 0 0 1'
```

I managed to write a script that rotates the script each time you call it:

https://gist.github.com/rubo77/daa262e0229f6e398766

Answer (score 0):

So I have all the transformations for touchscreen and touchpad on a laptop ... the trackpad physical orientation is assumed to be in front of the user, between user keyboard and eDP1. No matter which way i rotate the x display the mouse cursor moves in concert with finger on trackpad. I did this ages ago and forgot the logic. Now I added mirror on x and mirror on y transformations using `xrandr -x` and `xrandr -y`, but I cannot find the matrix coordinates for the trackpad so that cursor movement on screen is the same as finger movement on trackpad.

```
function rotate_left (){
    xrandr --output "$connected" --rotate left
    xinput set-prop "$touch" "Evdev Axis Inversion" 0, 1
    xinput set-prop "$touch" "Evdev Axes Swap" 1
    xinput set-prop "$pad" "$TRANSFORM" 0 -1 1 1 0 0 0 0 1
    xinput set-prop "$touch" "$TRANSFORM" 0 -1 1 1 0 0 0 0 1
    echo "left" >/etc/rotate
    echo "icon:$camino/icons/left.png" >>"$track"/ayp
}; export -f rotate_left

function rotate_right (){
    xrandr --output "$connected" --rotate right
    xinput set-prop "$touch" "Evdev Axis Inversion" 0, 1
    xinput set-prop "$touch" "Evdev Axes Swap" 1
    xinput set-prop "$pad" "$TRANSFORM" 0 1 0 -1 0 1 0 0 1
    xinput set-prop "$touch" "$TRANSFORM" 0 1 0 -1 0 1 0 0 1
    echo "right" >/etc/rotate
    echo "icon:$camino/icons/right.png" >>"$track"/ayp
}; export -f rotate_right

function rotate_inverted (){
    xrandr --output "$connected" --rotate inverted
    xinput set-prop "$touch" "Evdev Axis Inversion" 1, 1
    xinput set-prop "$touch" "Evdev Axes Swap" 0
    xinput set-prop "$pad" "$TRANSFORM" -1 0 1 0 -1 1 0 0 1
    xinput set-prop "$touch" "$TRANSFORM" -1 0 1 0 -1 1 0 0 1
    echo "inverted" >/etc/rotate
    echo "icon:$camino/icons/inverted.png" >>"$track"/ayp
}; export -f rotate_inverted

function rotate_normal (){
    xrandr --output "$connected" --rotate normal
    xinput set-prop "$touch" "Evdev Axis Inversion" 1, 1
    xinput set-prop "$touch" "Evdev Axes Swap" 1
    xinput set-prop "$pad" "$TRANSFORM" 1 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 1
    xinput set-prop "$touch" "$TRANSFORM" 1 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 1
    echo "normal" >/etc/rotate
    echo "icon:$camino/icons/normal.png" >>"$track"/ayp
}; export -f rotate_normal
function rotate_flipx {
    xrandr -x
    xinput set-prop "$touch" "Evdev Axis Inversion" 0,0
    xinput set-prop "$touch" "Evdev Axes Swap" 0
   xinput set-prop "$pad" "$TRANSFORM" 3 1 1 -1 1 1
    xinput set-prop "$touch" "$TRANSFORM" -1 0 1 0 -1 1 0 0 1
};export -f rotate_flipx
function rotate_flipy {
 xrandr -y
    xinput set-prop "$touch" "Evdev Axis Inversion" 0, 0
    xinput set-prop "$touch" "Evdev Axes Swap" 0
    xinput set-prop "$pad" "$TRANSFORM" 3 1 1 -1 1 1
    xinput set-prop "$touch" "$TRANSFORM" -1 0 1 0 -1 1 0 0 1
};export -f rotate_flipy
function rotate_flip_normal {
xrandr -o normal
    xinput set-prop "$touch" "Evdev Axis Inversion" 0, 0
    xinput set-prop "$touch" "Evdev Axes Swap" 0
    xinput set-prop "$pad" "$TRANSFORM" 1 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 1
    xinput set-prop "$touch" "$TRANSFORM" 1 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 1
};export rotate_flip_normal
```

Comment: Is this an answer to the existing question or a new question?